# saving props or state values without using Redux

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-props

So, I'm still a beginner with React and I'm trying to save state value of "quantity"

```
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          visible: false,
          selected: false,
          quantity: ""
        }
        this.toggleMenu = this.toggleMenu.bind(this);
    }
```

I want to pass this data to the component linked to the parent of this component and prevent losing data if I go back.

```
<Link to={`/itemSelection/${sessionStorage.getItem("")}/checkout`}>PROCEED</Link>
```

______________________________________________________-

EDITED

So the parent component is ItemSelection inside of it I import Item component and map through some data I get from api.

```
<div className="row">
                    {this.state.items.map(i => <Item name={i.name} quantity={i.quantity} />)}
                </div>
```

the quantity I pass to Item is the whole quantity I get from the api.

Inside of Item component

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      visible: false,
      selected: false,
      quantity: ""
    }
    this.toggleMenu = this.toggleMenu.bind(this);
}
```

the quantity here is the quantity I select for every item I choose. when I click the link to the checkout component I lose this data and if I go back to the itemSelection component I find these data lost also. So I want to pass this quantity of every item to the checkout component and prevent losing the data if I go back again to the itemSelection component. Hope this clarification make sense.

Comment: Maybe store the data in a cookie... https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-cookie

Answer (score 1):

Well, if I undestand this correct, you can two options. You can save the data on the **sessionStorage** and retrieve on the component ItemSelection or store the data on a component that is parent from both ItemSelection  and the checkout.